# .call{}() in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, payable

**This is a Smart Contract written in solidity, compiled and deployed in remix**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT OR Apache 2.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Payable{

    // payable address can send and receive ethers
    address payable public owner;

    // payable constructor can receive ethers
    constructor() payable{
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    // this function can receive ethers
    function deposit() public payable{}

    // this cannot accept ethers
    function nonPayable() public{}

    function withdraw() public {
        uint amount = address(this).balance;

        (bool success,) = owner.call{value:amount}("Amount Withdrawn from smart contract");

        require(success,"Failed to receive ether");
    }

    function transfer(address payable _to, uint _amount) public{
        (bool success,) = _to.call{value:_amount}("ether trransferred");
        require(success,"Failed to send ether to address");
    }
}
```

*It is recommended to use .call{}() instead of .transfer() or .send()*

I think **.call{}()** returns a tuple, containing status of transaction and a string memory which stores the string(Amount Withdrawn from smart contract).

If the transaction is successful this string is treated as a data parameter sent as a part of the low-level message call.

What is this low-level message call?

Where could I see this message getting passed in the console?

Is there any other use of this string?

Also I'm bit confused it is string or some function.

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/121606/how-does-the-function-call-work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**call** allows to send ether with a selected amount of gas to an Externally Owned Account or to another contract which implements the **receive()** or **fallback()** functions.

Additionally, a function in the target contract can be called with the parameter **call** function has. In this example, we will be calling the **myFunction** function, with arguments **7** and **true**:

> (bool success, ) = to.call{value: 1 ether, gas: 100000}(abi.encodeWithSignature("myFunction(uint,bool)", 7, true));

If the called function does not match with any function in the target contract, **fallback()** function will be called. If **fallback()** does not exist, the **success** variable returned will be **false**.

Comment: I think uint would be uint256.